# Get date from bootstrap-datepicker and print separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Date picker. I want to get date value(20-Sep-19) and print it in three different div's(so as i can style them differently).

```
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="hidden" id="date-input" value="20-Sep-19" class="form-control">
  <div id="div1">20 </div>
  <div id="div2">Sep'19</div>
  <div id="div3">Wednesday</div>
</div>

$(function(){
  $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-M-yy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true});
});
```

I have tried some jquery but doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("change", "#date-input", function () {
  var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
  day = date.getDate();
  month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  year = date.getFullYear();
  alert([day, month, year].join('/'));

});
```

Anyone know how this can be achieved. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the [changeDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) method instead of the `onchange` method? You would add this listener to the datepicker object directly

Comment: After getting date value how to print date separately in different divs?

Comment: Using jQuery you can target your div and input the text using `$("#div1").text(day);`

Comment: Thanks, but how do i get day from input, changeDate only trigger the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/zgwvnb4u/25/) for a quick implementation.

Your Javascript will need to parse the data sent back from the `dateChange` event of the `datepicker` element

```
picker.on("changeDate", function(e) {
        div1.text(e.date.getDate());

        var month = getMonthName(e.date.getMonth());
        var year = ("" + e.date.getYear()).substr(1, 3);
                div2.text(month + " '" + year);

        div3.text(getDayOfWeek(e.date.getDay()));
    });
```

The `getMonthName` and `getDayOfWeek` functions simply take in an integer and return the corresponding month/day.

From the sounds of things, you're relatively new to Javascript. I would highly recommend that you fully understand how to utilize Javascript and jQuery.
Please see the following resources for more information:
* [JS Date and utilities](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
* [jQuery .text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)
* [Bootstrap-datepicker changeDate documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)